# How can python pandas read excel file without unnamed columns

Tags: pandas, tableau-api, xlsx

I'd like to read a .xlsx using python pandas. The problem is the at the beginning of the excel file, it has some additional data like title or description of the table and tables contents starts. That introduce the unnamed columns because pandas DataReader takes it as the columns.
But tables contents starts after few lines later.

```
A                              B                     C
this is description
last updated: Mar 18th,2014
                               Table content
Country                        Year                 Product_output
Canada                         2017                 3002
Bulgaria                       2016                 2201
...
```

The table content starts in line 4. And columns must be "Country", "year", "proudct_output" instead "this is description", "unnamed", "unnamed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use `read_excel` function set `skiprows` paramter to 3.

Comment: Thanks. It's working. How can I detect the number of the rows beforehand? What I just know is that there are few rows, before the table body comes. How can I detect the number of rows that I have to skip?

Comment: If you know the name of the first column, you can open your file using Python's csv module and go through the rows until you find a match. Count how many rows that was and use that number in skiprows parameter.

Comment: I don't know the first column. I just know that each column has a filter on it. Is there any way to do that using that info?

Comment: I am not sure. I've never had to do something like that. There are some libraries made specifically for excel. Maybe you can try that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using index_col=[0] parameter
pd.read_excel('Excel_Sample.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1',index_col=[0])